# How to completely uninstall phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

PhpmyadminController handler class cannot be loaded
This comes up when I go to my website.com/phpmyadmin even though I have completely uninstalled phpmyadmin and reinstalled about 5 times and this still comes up.

Answer (score 1):

To really clean up everything you need to purge a package, otherwise your configuration will be kept and the package is only deleted.
Try

```
sudo dpkg --purge phpmyadmin
```

Comment: PhpmyadminController handler class cannot be loaded still comes up at mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin after using  sudo dpkg --purge phpmyadmin

Comment: This means you access your website mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin via browser and then you'll see the error? Then have a look in your web browser <document root directory>/phpmyadmin or look at your web browser's configuration if 'phpmyadmin' is an alias to another directory. In this directory there is still some index.php file that wants to load phpmyadmin but because it is deleted can not be loaded. Every new installation will not touch your browser configuration because it is already changed.

Comment: Yes I access my website via browser and I see the error, could you explain in more detail what I need to do (I'm very new to this.)

Comment: And also this error still happens even if phpMyAdmin is installed, no matter what I do it won't go away

Comment: Ah, sorry. In the comment above I wanted to go to your web server (!) <document root directory>/phpmyadmin or look at your web server's configuration. Do you know what web server (apache, nginx) the site mywebsite.com serves?