# phpmyadmin uninstalled, but still prompting for login via browser

Tags: uninstall, phpmyadmin

Discovered today that phpmyadmin is running on my public webservers(!). I immediately uninstalled it. That is, I thought I did until I went to [site]/phpmyadmin in my browser and found that the login prompt is still coming up.

I ran the apt-get utility first:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 266 not upgraded.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 523610 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
(Reading database ... 521935 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing phpmyadmin, directory '/usr/share/phpmyadmin' not empty so not removed
```

Then ran dpkg to confirm..it says it was uninstalled:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
dpkg-query: package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: phpmyadmin is not installed
```

Yet the browser still offers to log me in:

[image: phpmyadmin login prompt]

The one thing I did *not* do was remove the actual phpmyadmin database. I know I probably could have deleted it without negatively impacting anything, but the site these servers host is very, very high visibility and I didn't want to risk it. I didn't think leaving an orphaned database would cause any issues (beyond a bit of wasted disk space).

Is there some manually step I need to take beyond what's been done?

PS I found a similar question here, but it was over a year old and there was no resolution posted:
[How to completely uninstall phpMyAdmin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647637/how-to-completely-uninstall-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line in the apt-get output you posted:

`dpkg: warning: while removing phpmyadmin, directory '/usr/share/phpmyadmin' not empty so not removed`

So something is still left in the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` directory and these files are probably prompting for login when you access them via web browser.
Check the contents of that directory and if there's nothing inside that's important for you, just delete that directory. That should fix the issue.

Comment: That was it. It was the (hidden) .htaccess directory that was snagging me. I guess my eyes just glossed over that line in the apt-get output. I nuked the phpmyadmin directory and now and getting a beautiful 404 pages as expected. Thanks!